# return values after timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to return value after timeout in this function

```
$get: function($timeout) {
        var breadcrumbs;
        data = [];

        $timeout(function() {
          data = crateBreadcrumbs();
          console.log(data);
        });
        return data;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a promise. The promise will signify that you have not yet returned data, but you will resolve that promise once your $timeout service is completed.

You can use the `$q` service to achieve this. [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Essentially,

```
function($timeout) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function() {
        data = createBreadcrumbs();
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }, 1000);

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Per @Bergi's comment,

```
$get: function($timeout) {
    return $timeout(function() { return createBreadcrumbs();})
}
```

Comment: `$timeout` already returns a promise. Avoid the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: thanks alex and @Bergi